# How to highlight angular brackets in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing C++ code and it hurts when I browse those STL code where templates are nested like hell. Is there a option in VS settings where I can toggle angular bracket highlighting? Or a plugin that can help with this issue?

Comment: there's https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora which highlights different pairs of brackets with different colors. Unfortunately looks like it only supports `[](){}` so you may want to create a ticket there

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that VS does not directly set the highlighting of `<>`. However, I suggest that you could visit `studiostyle` official website. There are many code styles, including the highlighting of `<>`.